# What wrong with my code on css overflow hidden property?

Tags: css, overflow, hidden

I want to hide the overflown content from div id="windowPanel" so when I call certain div element in Js it will scroll to that element.

I played around with div positioning but cant get it work, heres my code:

```
body {
    width:auto;
}


#windowpanel {
    width:800px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden ;
    position:relative;

}

.bannerContainer {
    width:100%;
    height:500%;
    position:absolute;

}

.itemContainer {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    display:block;
    position:relative;

}

.photoItem {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

.textItem {
    float:left;
    width:50%;

}

.navItem {
    float:left;
    top:200px;
    left:600px;
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;


}

<div id="windowPanel">
    <div class="bannerContainer">
        <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="textItem">Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus. Donec magna leo sapien augue tellus, phasellus erat, adipiscing lectus phasellus enim nulla, eu aliquam sodales</div>
        <div class="photoItem"><img class="" src="images/target.png" width="350" height="248" alt="image1" /></div>
        <div class="navItem">
            <a class="navItemLink" /> Nav here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="textItem">Text here</div>
        <div class="photoItem">Photo Here</div>
        <div class="navItem">Nav here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="textItem">Text here</div>
        <div class="photoItem">Photo Here</div>
        <div class="navItem">Nav here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="textItem">Text here</div>
        <div class="photoItem">Photo Here</div>
        <div class="navItem">Nav here</div>
        </div>

        <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="textItem">Text here</div>
        <div class="photoItem">Photo Here</div>
        <div class="navItem">Nav here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think there is some problem with your `height:500%;` in `.bannerContainer` class coz it increases the size of your relative div `windowpanel` i have not tried any work out.

Comment: hmm both didnt solve the problem

Comment: Can you use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to post the example? That way someone can better help you.

Comment: yes, thanks this is the link to the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mgcBa/

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of things wrong. I have fixed it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgcBa/13/).

1. Your `<div>` had an id "windowPanel", but your CSS selector was
   "#windowpanel". CSS selectors are case-sensitive.
2. `<a>` tags can not be self closed.
3. You will have to explicitly define the height in 'px' if the children are floated or you should clear the floats.